# Fermat's Little Theorem implementation in R

Tags: r

This is a very rudimentary implementation of the fermat's little theorem in R. However, it gives warning messages at n=59. 
Warning message:
In ifelse(m != 0, n%%m, n) : probable complete loss of accuracy in modulus. Can someone please endeavour to help me skirt around this issue or suggest a simple solution for R?

pcheck=

```
  function(n){
    two=rep(2,n)
    pv=vector(length=n)
    for (i in 3:n){
      if (
        mod(two[i]^(i-1),i)==1 ### from the numbers package
      )
        pv[i]=TRUE
      else
        pv[i]=FALSE

    }
    pv
  }
```

Comment: Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0ZQvZLx2KA

Comment: For those who are interested this ignores 1 and 2 at the moment.

Comment: check out the solution here, it could be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580717/modulus-warning-in-r-lehmann-primality-test

Comment: @ erasmortg: Thanks had a look already. Can't really understand what they have done with modexp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `modpower` function from the library you are using, `numbers`, to get around the big integer problem.

```
f2 <- function(n) sapply(1:n, function(i) modpower(2, (i-1), i) == 1)
seq(59)[f2(59)]
# [1]  1  3  5  7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59
```

Comment: @nongkong. Thank you sir.

Comment: @nongkong - thank you, thank you, thank you  you are champ!